# Why fusion::map<> types not the same

Tags: boost-fusion

Why `type` is not same as `expected` in the example below?

```
using origin = boost::fusion::map<
    boost::fusion::pair<int, int>
>;
using expected = boost::fusion::map<
     boost::fusion::pair<int, int>
    ,boost::fusion::pair<char, char>
>;

using type = boost::fusion::result_of::push_back<
     origin
    ,boost::fusion::pair<char, char>
>::type;

static_assert(std::is_same<expected, type>::value, "error!");
```

The second question is, how can I get the same type as `expected` when using `result_of::push_back<>::type` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `fusion::result_of::as_map`.

```
using origin = boost::fusion::map<
    boost::fusion::pair<int, int>
>;
using expected = boost::fusion::map<
     boost::fusion::pair<int, int>
    ,boost::fusion::pair<char, char>
>;

using type = typename boost::fusion::result_of::as_map<
    typename boost::fusion::result_of::push_back<
         origin
        ,boost::fusion::pair<char, char>
    >::type
>::type;
```

Comment: I think you can also use [`static_assert(boost::mpl::equal<expected, type>::value, "error!");`](http://www.boost.org/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/equal.html) (including "boost/mpl/equal.hpp").